# esbuild: How to prevent transpiled js from using eval?

Tags: javascript, bundler, esbuild

I am trying to make a chrome extension with esbuild and ts react with a build file that looks something like this.

```
require('esbuild')
    .build({
        entryPoints: [
            'src/contentScript.ts',
            'src/index.html',
        ],
        outdir: 'dist',
        bundle: true,
        platform: 'browser',
        banner: {
              js: `var regeneratorRuntime;`,
        }
    })
    .catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

When I build my project, the transpiled code contains the following:

```
Script.prototype.runInThisContext = function() {
            return eval(this.code);
          }
```

The use of eval is unacceptable for a chrome extension due to security concerns. So how do I configure esbuild to NOT use `eval`? I saw a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1006) of a similar problem but adding `banner: {       js:` var regeneratorRuntime;`,     },` did not stop esbuild from using eval. Please help!

Comment: I'm not sure about esbuild, but in webpack this is a function of the output you choose. Have you already tried different output formats? https://esbuild.github.io/api/#format

Comment: I tried iife, cjs, and esm and all outputs contained eval https://esbuild.github.io/api/#format